# For some reason when I post " having i" to a php page it is giving me a Forbidden You don't have permission to access on this server. Error

Tags: php, post

This happens only with that odd string (that I have found so far) and even on the most simple of set ups (one input, only that string, posted to a blank processing page). Anyone run into anything like this?

Example of code that causes the error (Forbidden You don't have permission to access on this server.):

```
<?php
//this is what is on basic1.php
?>
<form method="post" action="basic1.php">
<input id="currchat" name="currchat" >
<button type="submit" ></button>
</form>
```

Comment: When you add the odd string to what?

Comment: Please share the code that you're using where this happens.

Comment: probably a very stupid anti-sql injection defense system. You'd probably get the same error with `select i` or `; drop table students`

Comment: Yeah I thought that a possibility so I tried a bunch of sql and only " having i" causes the problem thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by mod_sec our host Namecheap had activated, the specfic line and id that caused this in mod_sec was: [line "390"] [id "211720"]